# Does the place of the sigmoid function matter in neural network?

Tags: neural-network, keras, backpropagation

I am trying to build a neural net in python using Keras with a custom loss and I was wandering whether having a sigmoid function as an activation function in the last layer and having a sigmoid in the beginning of the custom loss is the same or not. So here is what I mean by that:

[image]

I have a feeling that in the second model the loss is calculated but it is not back propagated through the sigmoid meanwhile in the first model it is. Is that right?

Comment: Could you provide us a code which you are using - this is actually really interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, in the second case the backpropagation doesn't go through the sigmoid. It is a really bad thing to alter data inside of the loss function.

The reason this is a bad thing to do is because then, you will backpropagate an error on the output which is not the real error that the network is making.

Explaining myself with a simple case:
you have labels in a binary form say a tensor `[0, 0, 1, 0]`
If your sigmoid is inside your custom loss function, you might have outputs that look like this `[-100, 0, 20, 100],` the sigmoid in your loss will transform this into something looking approximately like tihs :`[0, 0.5, 1, 1]`
The error that will be backpropagated will then be `[0, -0.5, 0, -1]`. The backpropagation will **not** take into account the sigmoid and you will apply this error directly to the output. You can see that the magnitude of the error doesn't reflect at all the magnitude of the output's error: the last value is 100 and should be in negative territory, but the model will backpropagate a small error of -1 on that layer.

To summarize, the sigmoid must be in the network so that the backpropagation takes it into account when backpropagating the error.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for your answer I really appreciate it